# Need help debugging kafka latency for high frequency data

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have an IoT device that is streaming data to a python server every 15ms. The python server uploads the data to kafka and another server consumes it.

I have a partition key for the data based on sensor id. The latency for the first few messages are sub 30ms, but then it skyrockets to 500ms before slowly coming down and then repeating (image below).

[image]

My assumption here is that the producer is batching the data before sending it. I can't seem to find a setting to turn this off so that my latency is consistent. Issue seems to happen even if I have a blank message.

Here's the code for my producer

```
producer = KafkaProducer(
    bootstrap_servers=get_kafka_brokers(),
    security_protocol='SSL',
    ssl_context=get_kafka_ssl_context(),
    value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'),
    batch_size=0,
    acks=1
)
message = {}
producer.send(app.config['NEW_LOG_TOPIC'], message, key=str(device.id).encode('utf-8'))
```

I have been reading the [documentation](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaProducer.html) up and down and have tried several different configurations but nothing has helped. My servers and kafka instance are running on heroku.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you also share your consumer config, `fetch.min.bytes` and `fetch.max.wait.ms` in particular?

Comment: I didn't think to check the consumer. Reducing fetch.max.wait.ms seems to be the solution. Now my latency is averaging around a 100. Thanks!